# How can I perform "iterative" one-step forecasts by updating my dataset with actual values using loops in R

Tags: r, time-series, iteration, forecasting, forecast

I am working with the following datasets containing 1 years worth of hourly price data:

- Training (data from 2014-01-01 00:00 until 2014-12-31 23:00)
- Test (data from 2015-01-01 00:00 until 2015-12-31 23:00)

I want to use the training dataset to fit a model and perform day-ahead hourly price forecasting for the year 2015, whilst updating the training dataset to include newly available hourly price data for each day. Finally, I want compare the forecasts with the actual values in my test set.

To begin, I want to use the `snaive` (Seasonal Naive) method
 from the `forecast` package in R to set a benchmark.

As the definition of my problem is day-ahead price forecasting, I want to perform the forecasts in this sequence:

1. Train the model on the whole training dataset (containing hourly price info from 2014-01-01 00:00 until 2014-12-31 23:00)
2. Use the model to perform a one-step forecast of the next 24 hours (i.e. the prices for 2015-01-01 00:00-23:00)
3. Store the predictions in a `Predictions` matrix
4. Update the training set to include the 24 **actual** hourly price values of 2015-01-01 00:00-23:00
5. Retrain the model on this new training training dataset (this time containing hourly price info from 2014-01-01 00:00 until 2015-01-01 23:00)
6. Use the new model to perform a one-step forecast of the next 24 hours (i.e. the prices for 2015-01-02 00:00-23:00)
7. Store the predictions in a `Predictions` matrix
8. [...]
9. Repeat the above until all forecasts up to 2015-12-31 00:00-23:00 are completed and stored in the `Predictions` matrix
10. Measure the forecast accuracy vs. test data.

My guess is that a for loop would work in this case, however I am failing miserably in trying to get a working loop that performs the desired sequence of operations.

Any help on how to create a working loop would be greatly appreciated!

A follow-up question would be whether a loop is the most efficient way of achieving my desired results?

Thank you!
BalysLTU

EDIT: I have shared the datasets in a [Google Drive Folder here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fKmicVussnFl_8cyA-Mxzr6ObwcAnb7G?usp=sharing).

What I'm trying to do would be something like this:

```
# Reading/cleaning data #

df.elspot.prices.2014 <- as.data.frame(
  read_excel(paste0(dirDataPrices, "elspot-prices_2014_hourly_eur.xlsx"), skip = 2)
)
df.elspot.prices.2015 <- as.data.frame(
  read_excel(paste0(dirDataPrices, "elspot-prices_2015_hourly_eur.xlsx"), skip = 2)

# Training models and updating datasets #

df.elspot.prices.test <- rbind(df.elspot.prices.2014, df.elspot.prices.2015[0,])
msts.elspot.prices.test <- msts(df.elspot.prices.test$Price, seasonal.periods = c(24, 168), ts.frequency = 8760, start = 2014) 
df.elspot.predictions.2015  <- as.data.frame(meanf(msts.elspot.prices.test, h = 24)$mean)

df.elspot.prices.test <- rbind(df.elspot.prices.2014, df.elspot.prices.2015[1:24,])
msts.elspot.prices.test <- msts(df.elspot.prices.test$Price, seasonal.periods = c(24, 168), ts.frequency = 8760, start = 2014) 
df.elspot.predictions.2015  <- as.data.frame(meanf(msts.elspot.prices.test, h = 24)$mean)

df.elspot.prices.test <- rbind(df.elspot.prices.2014, df.elspot.prices.2015[1:48,])
msts.elspot.prices.test <- msts(df.elspot.prices.test$Price, seasonal.periods = c(24, 168), ts.frequency = 8760, start = 2014) 
df.elspot.predictions.2015  <- as.data.frame(meanf(msts.elspot.prices.test, h = 24)$mean)

...

df.elspot.prices.test <- rbind(df.elspot.prices.2014, df.elspot.prices.2015[1:87636,])
msts.elspot.prices.test <- msts(df.elspot.prices.test$Price, seasonal.periods = c(24, 168), ts.frequency = 8760, start = 2014) 
df.elspot.predictions.2015  <- as.data.frame(meanf(msts.elspot.prices.test, h = 24)$mean)
```

Comment: why do you need the loop? Just split the data into full dataset and dataset - testing period, fit the model on training get the predictions, calculate performance

Comment: if you need to perform a rolling cv there is already a function for that in the forecast package it is called `tsCV`, the answer on when the loop is the best choice is almost never

Comment: And before I forget and just rant, Welcome to SO, try to post a reprex when you ask questions

Comment: Thank you @Bruno, I've posted an edit to my original question w/ the data and the code example of what I'm trying to achieve with the loops.
To answer your question on why the loop and not splitting the data into full datasets - that would mean that I would be performing a yearly forecast, rather than a day-ahead forecast. As price data becomes available every day, I want to be able to use that new data as input for the model.

Comment: Yes `tsCV` solves exactly that problem, I won't dowload a google spreasheet, look into the dput function

Comment: Okay, I will look into ```tsCV```. Appreciate the heads-up @Bruno! But what is the ```dput``` function and why should I look into that?

Comment: The dput function gives back the structure of your data, then you paste that structure in stack overflow and I don't have to try to open your google sheets